# Profiling output of JIT on Linux with perf_events/oprofile?

Tags: linux, profiling, jit, oprofile, perf

I want to profile code, generated by JIT on Linux, with using hardware performace counters. As I know, most common profilers are `oprofile` and `perf`.

How can I integrate JIT and oprofile/perf?

My JIT is not JAVA which is already supported in oprofile. (perf?)

For example we can consider LLVM's JIT. I want to

1. See the hottest functions (their names) from JIT-ted code
2. See the disassembly of hottest function, with performance counter statistics assigned to every instruction

Comment: May be [opagent](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/doc/devel/index.html) for oprofile?

Comment: And for perf there was patch ["perf report: Add support for profiling JIT generated code"](http://lwn.net/Articles/474254/) by penberg@ to support Jato JVM's JIT via `/tmp/perf-$PID.map` symbol(?) file. Format is "Startaddr size name\n". This file must be readable by `perf report`

Comment: and here is the perf patch: https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/6/8/499 "perf report: Add support for profiling JIT generated code"

Comment: And for oprofile there is the support code: `llvm/lib/ExecutionEngine/OProfileJIT/OProfileWrapper.cpp` thanks to http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2013-March/060153.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To profile JITed code using perf, download, compile and install the [perf-map-agent](https://github.com/jrudolph/perf-map-agent) library, then (for java code anyway) add the 
`-agentpath:<path>/libperfmap.so` to the command line.

For non-java code, as long as the `/tmp/perf-$pid.map` symbol map files are generated, perf 
will use those when it produces perf reports.

Brendan Gregg has a [blog post](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-09-17/node-flame-graphs-on-linux.html) that has related references.

Comment: seacoder, thank you. What is the format of `/tmp/perf-$pid.map`? When does perf access it, in `record`, after `record` or in `report` subcommand? How can I have the disassembly of JIT-generated code?

Comment: The map files contains entries in the format of <address> <size> <label> on each line.  For an example, take a look at the section on 'v8 --perf-basic-prof support' on [this blog](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-09-17/node-flame-graphs-on-linux.html).  The temp files are accessed when you run `perf report`.  I think you can access the disassembly via `perf report` options.  Perf documentation should explain how to do that.

Comment: seacoder, I can access disassembly of the static machine code with perf report, but not of JIT-generated code. The code, made by JIT is deleted at time of perf report and copy of this machine code is not saved.

Comment: osgx, I have not attempted to disassemble JITed code using `perf`, so I will have to defer to the perf docs on that.